# ChartJS multiple dataset issue. second dataset gets over 1st instead of overlaying

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Please check this image.. currently there is two dataset.. but i can have more... the main issue is that why it gets out of boundery and over another dataset?

[image]

Link
    http://codepen[dot]io/anon/pen/womMmR

PS. i could not post the codepen link directly 
better editing will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `stacked: true` from your y-axis configuration. `stacked: true` is for stacking each dataset on top of the previous dataset. In other words, this is for drawing each chart above the previous chart, as if the previous chart defined `y = 0`. That is why the height of the stacked chart becomes greater than `max`, although all values across all datasets are lower than `max`.